# How the crystal structure varying for the same compound?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

i have synthesized the crystal Cyclohexylammonium acetate. Structure of this compound was already solved and it s under centro symmetric space group I2/a. But when i took single crystal analysis it comes under monoclinic C2/c space group. What is the reason for getting this kind of results?

Comment: This may pretty well be _the same_ group in different settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a) Your structure analysis is wrong

or

b) the publication is wrong (your looked up the wrong substance, typo in the original work, ...)

or

c) You crystallised from another solvent, at different temperature, (pressure?) and got another modification.